# Библиотека AIOGRAM Python, телеграмм бот, машина состояний не "подхватывает" координаты:

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, location

```
    async def load_place(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext): 
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        # data['name'] = message.text
        data['place'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.reply('TEXT', reply_markup=kb_place1)



#Ловим последний ответ
async def load_place1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):<== Вот тут что писать чтоб 
                                                                     подхватывало? 
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        print(types)
 
        if message.location is not None:
            data['latitude'] = message.location.latitude
            data['longitude'] = message.location.longitude
            data['user_ID'] = message.from_user.id

        else:
            data['latitude'] = message.text
            data['longitude'] = message.text
            data['user_ID'] = message.from_user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Не корректно поставил вопрос. Нужно было поменять в хендлере content_types:

dp.register_message_handler(load_place1, content_types=['location', 'text'], state=FSMAdmin.place1)

Спасибо!)